# Unable to display overlay template in ag-grid when url fails

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm trying to show overlay template when the service URL fails in ag-grid.

But the overlay message is not displaying as expected.

I wanted to show `Service URL failed` message when the http request fails. And another overlay message `Please wait data is loading` when data is actually loading in the grid.

I'm unable to display the overlay message when the url gets failed. it always show's the first message

How do i fix this ?

This my link to the plunker project : https://plnkr.co/edit/MzpwnE0enLx2PVJOFUyn?p=preview

**Note: to replicate the issue, give some invalid http url**

```js
this._Service.httpPost(b, a)
  .retryWhen((err) => {
    return err.scan((retryCount) => {
      retryCount += 1;
      if (retryCount < 3) {
        return;
      } else {
        this.gridOptions.overlayNoRowsTemplate = '<span class="messageStyles">Problem with service link. Please try again later</span>';
        this.gridOptions.api.showNoRowsOverlay();
        throw (err);
      }
    }, 0).delay(1000);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    return Observable.of(err);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code below, it only update rows in case data is there, else shows the error.

You might need to handle scenario in a different way where in you check if its due to service error or the data is actually empty or due to some other error. I didn't handle that situation in the code.

```
onGridReady(params) {
this.gridApi = params.api;
this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;

this.http
  .get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-doc1s/master/src/olympicWinnersSmall.json")
    .retryWhen((err) => {
              return err.scan((retryCount) => {
                retryCount += 1;
                if ( retryCount < 3 ) {
                  this.overlayLoadingTemplate = '<span class="messageStyles">Problem with service link. Please try again later</span>';
                    this.gridApi.showLoadingOverlay();
                    this.gridApi.refreshCells(params);
                //  return;
                } else {
                   this.overlayLoadingTemplate = '<span class="messageStyles">Problem with service link. Please try again later</span>';
                    this.gridApi.showLoadingOverlay();
                    this.gridApi.refreshCells(params);
                  throw(err);
                }
              }, 0).delay(1000);
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
              return Observable.of(err);
            })
     .subscribe(data => {
            if(!data || !data.length)
             {
               this.gridApi.showLoadingOverlay();
             }else
             {
                params.api.setRowData(data);    
             }
      });
```

}

Comment: Thanks. But this message will be display for both `Service Error 404` and `No Data to display`. I need to display different overlay message

Comment: This example lacks the binding of overlayLoadingTemplate to the ag-grid so it can not work as-is. How to template the messages is written here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-overlay-component/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the message, modify the `localeTextFunc` of the grid API to return a different message. For this example to work you should bind *gridOptions* to the grid e.g. `<ag-grid-angular [gridOptions]="gridOptions"...`, then, on error call *ShowErrorOverlay()*.

```
import { GridOptions } from '@ag-grid-community/core';
```

...

```
gridOptions: GridOptions;
private origLocaleTextFunc: any;
private errLocaleTextFunc: any;

ngInit() {
    this.gridOptions = this.getDefaultGridOptions(this);
    this.origLocaleTextFunc = this.gridOptions.localeTextFunc;
    this.errLocaleTextFunc = (key, defaultValue) => {
        if (key === 'noRowsToShow') {
            return 'Error!';
        } else {
            return this.origLocaleTextFunc(key, defaultValue);
        }
    };
}



getDefaultGridOptions(context: any): GridOptions {
    const rv = {} as GridOptions;
    rv.localeTextFunc = (key, defaultValue) => {
        switch (key) {
            case 'noRowsToShow': return 'No rows!';
            default: return defaultValue;
        }
    };

    rv.context = { componentParent: context };
    return rv;
}



showErrorOverlay() {
    this.gridOptions.localeTextFunc = this.errLocaleTextFunc; // set error msgs
    this.gridOptions.api.showNoRowsOverlay();
    this.gridOptions.localeTextFunc = this.origLocaleTextFunc; // set default msgs
}
```

If you need to style the message, look into https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-overlay-component/ or just modify your `.ag-overlay-no-rows-wrapper` and    `.ag-overlay-no-rows-center` classes